# How to redirect old parameter based content without jeopardizing SEO

Tags: seo, apache, url-rewriting, pagerank

We have a large scale ecommerce site that has pretty high PageRank and tops google results in a few keywords, the current issue is that we have revamped our search which now uses SEO friendly urls to replace our old ID based URLs. I am not sure what the best method is to redirect / convert these old urls into the new format without hurting our rank any help would be appreciated.

Here is an example :

OLD format:

```
http://www.example.com/rugsusa/control/style-search/~cid=7005
```

New format:

```
http://www.example.com/rugsusa/control/search-contemporary-rugs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a 301 redirect from the old links to the new links should carry the SEO you've built up to the new links. For example, [Google's Webmaster Support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) says

> "If you need to change the URL of a page as it is shown in search engine results, we recommend that you use a server-side 301 redirect."